# MySQL nearest date without duplicated data

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join, greatest-n-per-group

So I need to display all my customers and with the associated booking number (null if there is no booking) without duplicated custome. If the customer has lot of bookings I need to display only the nearest booking date. I don't understand why my query doesn't work.

Here is what is did : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df0455/19

```
SELECT c.name, x.number, x.start_date
FROM customer c 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT b.customer_id, b.number, b.start_date
 FROM booking b
 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT customer_id, MIN(ABS(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), start_date)))) as mindiff
    FROM booking
    GROUP BY customer_id
  ) nearest ON b.customer_id = nearest.customer_id AND ABS(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), start_date))) = mindiff
) AS x ON c.id = x.customer_id
```

Actually `Paul` is displayed three times and what is need is to display `Paul` just once with the nearest booking number who is `booking-1 2019-11-05 21:45:00`

I hope you can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with a row-limiting correlated subquery:

```
select c.name, b.number, b.start_date
from customer c
inner join booking b on b.customer_id = c.id
where b.start_date = (
    select b1.start_date
    from booking b1
    where b1.customer_id = b.customer_id
    order by abs(timestampdiff(second, now(), b1.start_date)) 
    limit 1
)
```

In your DB Fiddle, **[this produces](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df0455/20)**:

```
name    number     start_date
Paul    booking-1   2019-11-05T21:45:00Z
John    booking-3   2019-09-27T21:45:00Z
Morgan  booking-5   2019-09-27T21:45:00Z
```

If you wanted to also display customers without bookings, then you would `left join` and move the filtering to the `on` clause of the `join`:

```
select c.name, b.number, b.start_date
from customer c
left join booking b 
    on b.customer_id = c.id
    and b.start_date = (
        select b1.start_date
        from booking b1
        where b1.customer_id = b.customer_id
        order by abs(timestampdiff(second, now(), b1.start_date)) 
        limit 1
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it works very nice, just one think what I need it's to display the customer even he doesn't associated to a booking. I'd like to display just the name then null for booking, I tried left join on your query but it doesn't work to you know why ?

Comment: @John: you need to move the `where` clause to a join condition. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to get the *nearest booking* and join to customer:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, t.number, t.start_date
FROM customer c 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT b.* FROM booking b
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM booking
    WHERE customer_id = b.customer_id 
      AND ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), start_date)) < ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), b.start_date))
  )  
) t ON t.customer_id = c.id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aBW9eE4c86UFh4t9ZzPsNk/1).
Results:

```
| id  | name   | number    | start_date          |
| --- | ------ | --------- | ------------------- |
| 1   | Paul   | booking-1 | 2019-11-05 21:45:00 |
| 2   | John   | booking-3 | 2019-09-27 21:45:00 |
| 3   | Morgan | booking-5 | 2019-09-27 21:45:00 |
| 4   | Jane   |           |                     |
| 5   | Mike   |           |                     |
```